Does Increasing Dimensionality Before Compression Make Sense for Anomaly Detection with Autoencoders?
Given a dataset $X$ of shape $(n, p)$ such that $n \gg 1$ and $p \approx 10$, I would like to train an autoencoder to solve an anomaly detection problem.
I did some experiments considering a classical architecture described by:
$$\mathcal{A} = \Phi \circ \Psi$$
with
$$\Phi = \Phi_{p_3} \circ \Phi_{p_2} \circ \Phi_{p_1}$$
such that $p > p_1 > p_2 > p_3$, and symmetrically for $\Psi$. This led to good results but not better than the ones of an architecture where $p < p_1$ and $p_1 > p_2 > p_3$. My question is: theoretically, does it make sense to consider this second architecture as it does not directly compress the data into lower dimensionalities, but first increases it to extract nonlinear features?
